# The notation $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}G$ in Robinson's "A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)".

Tags: group-theory, notation, tensor-products, abelian-groups

There appears to be anachronistic notation in Robinson's book *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*, page 105, **Exercise 4.2.8**.

*NB:* This is a [notation](/questions/tagged/notation) question.

### The Details:

The exercise reads

> (Dieudonné). Let $\mu:A\to B$ be a monomorphism of abelian groups and let $G$ be a torsion-free abelian group. Prove that $\mu_*:A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}G\to B\otimes_{\Bbb Z}G$ is a monomorphism where $(a\otimes g)\mu_*=(a\mu)\otimes g.$ [*Hint:* Reduce first to the case where $G$ is finitely generated and then to the case $G=\Bbb Z$.]

### The Question:

What does Robinson mean by "$A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}G$" here exactly? Is it defined earlier on in the text? (I can't find it anywhere . . . )

### Thoughts:

I believe it is the tensor product. The book doesn't say anything about tensor products until page 131 outside the exercises (as far as I can tell), and even then, they're not defined. It's strange because Robinson goes to the trouble of defining, say, semigroups, and builds up basic concepts, but then expects the reader to know what a tensor product is.

Granted, the book *is* a graduate textbook. It doesn't define what a vector space is, either, for example, but refers to one in **Exercise 4.2.6**.

Please help :)

Comment: I'm assuming they mean $\mu_*(a \otimes g) = \mu(a) \otimes g$ right? And yes, I do think they're referring to tensor products (which is why it's so important for $G$ to be torsion-free).

Comment: Maps are written on the right of their arguments in the book, @MarkSaving.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen anyone write maps like this (apart from obscure programming languages which use reverse polish notation).

Comment: @MarkSaving: I've seen places where people write group actions on the right. Plain functions, not so much (except when it's not obvious what is the function and what is the argument...).

Comment: I believe you are right, it is meant to be the tensor product. Maybe the author is assuming that the reader is already familiar with basic linear/commutative algebra? It's not so odd to teach vector spaces before groups, though it is odder to teach *modules* before groups. In any event, if it's a graduate textbook, they might assume that the reader is actually familiar with the basics of the subject matter (and still partially recount them, if only to ensure that the important stuff is well understood).

Comment: @MarkSaving: There are several group theory books that were originally written in the 60s and 70s that use "functions on the right" notation (e.g., Hanna Neumann's *Varieties of Groups*); also, a *lot* of ring theorists use functions on the right: e.g., they make morphisms of modules look like associativity ($(rm)f = r(mf)$) and makes left $R$-modules into $R$-$\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ bimodules. It drifted in group theory, and people who work a lot with group actions seem to like the notation.

Comment: This is the "tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$": the universal object that codes bilinear maps from $A\times G$.. I don't have the book in front of me (it's in my office), so I can't check if he's defined it, but I can take a look on Monday.

Comment: Thank you, @ArturoaMagidin. I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are $A,B,G$ as defined in the question?

Comment: Given any two abelian groups $A$ and $B$, $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$, together with bilinear map $\iota\colon A\times B\to A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$ is the unique abelian group (up to unique isomorphism) with the following universal property: given any abelian group $G$ and any bilinear map $f\colon A\times B \to G$ there exists a unique abelian group homomorphism $F\colon A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B\to G$ such that $f = F\circ\iota$.

Comment: An explicit construction is that $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ is the quotient of the free abelian group on the symbols $a\otimes b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, subject to the relations $(a+a')\otimes b - a\otimes b - a'\otimes b$, $a\otimes(b+b') - a\otimes b - a\otimes b'$, with $a,a'$ ranging over all elements of $A$ and $b,b'$ ranging over all elements of $B$.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to call this anachronistic. Abelian group can be regarded as ${\mathbb Z}$-modules, and their tensor product is then defined as a tensor product of modules.

Comment: But $\Bbb Z$-modules aren't covered in the preceeding material either, @DerekHolt.

Comment: [Here is a question itself.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4215127/104041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor product is defined on p. 235 in the chapter on representations (8.4), despite being used earlier.